# error not found type DataType in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to wrap the defined Scala function into a transformation using pipeline

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, UnaryTransformer} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.{MLWritable, MLWriter}  

class UDFTransformer[T, U](override valuid: String, 
                       f: T =>U, inType: DataType,outType: DataType)
```

And I am getting error

> error: not found: type DataType

I have imported all the necessary files i don't know what i am missing or why I am getting this error

The rest of the code is

```
extendsUnaryTransformer[T, U, UDFTransformer[T, U]] with MLWritable {  
override protected defcreateTransformFunc: T =>U = f 
override protected defvalidateInputType(inputType: DataType): Unit = require(inputType == inType) 
override protected defoutputDataType: DataType = outType 
override defwrite: MLWriter = new MLWriter {
override protected defsaveImpl(path: String): Unit = {}
} 
}
```

UDFTransformer class wraps a function f, which accepts a generic type T, and produces type U. At the Spark dataset level, it transforms an input column (see UnaryTransformer) of type inType into a new output column (again, the field is defined by UnaryTransformer) of the outType type. The class also has a dummy implementation of the trait MLWritable, which supports serialization of the transformer into a file.

Comment: Could you please add some more code here , what the class is doing? Since you have imported the spark.sql.types._ maybe the scala compiler is not able to find something in the class code

Comment: Please update the question with this additional information

Comment: i have done the above please go through it once